# How to use js functions from laravel-mix file (webpack) in other js files included later via view file?

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I have a project where I use laravel mix to generate one minified js file used on whole page.

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.config.publicPath = 'public_html';
mix.js([
    'public_html/themes/sagafrontend/js/jquery-1.9.1.js',
    'public_html/themes/sagafrontend/js/jquery-ui.js',
    'public_html/themes/sagafrontend/js//main.js',
    'public_html/themes/sagafrontend/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'public_html/themes/sagafrontend/js/custom.js',
    'public_html/themes/sagafrontend/js/custom2.js',
], 'public_html/themes/sagafrontend/js/app.js')
    .version();
```

Minified file contains  lozad function(from dependency in package.json) which is using observer to lazy load images on whole page.

```
var lozad = require('lozad');
var observer = lozad();
observer.observe();
```

On product page I have added new filtering function which is calling ajax to filter products on given product list page. In short version it looks like this:

```
function filterProducts(filterVariables) {
        var path = '/productFilter';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: path,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                filterVariables: filterVariables
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('.filter-container').empty().append(data.products);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, thrown) {
            }
        });
}
```

And it's works fine - products are added to page via ajax.
Filter functions are in **separate file** loaded in  laravel **view** because I'm using filters **only** in **one view**  so there is no need to put whole code in global min file (this one generated via laravel mix).

```
@section('pageScripts')
<script src="{{ asset('themes/sagafrontend/js/filters.js') }}" defer></script>
@endsection
```

Problem is that products appended to page are not visible for observer and images paths are not updated. So after calling filters   *img data-src*  is not changed to *img src*.  In result no images are loaded.

Filters.js is a classic js file with functions so I cannot  use  require('lozad') to call observer on him. It will throw an error *'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined'* Is there a fairly simple way to access lozad and call observer without putting everything in one js file?